# accessing value of a python @property from a subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, descriptor

I'm trying to rework an oauthlib implementation into a pyramid app and ran into an issue with some default values on `@property` decorated class defs.

I am somehow exposing the property objects, and not calling/executing them.

Can anyone suggest a good way to 'execute' these properties?  It seems like calling `fget` with any object/None works:

```
self.propertyname.fget(self)
```

This seems very awkward though -- as does this entire issue.  I seem to be implementing something the wrong way.

The context of this problem, is trying to load some values from a configuration dict and falling back onto a property of the base class.  The basic form is below, and advice on a better implementation would be gladly accepted.

```
class Parent(object):
    @property
    def fieldname(self):
        """returns a tuple"""
        return (1, 10)

class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def fieldname(self):
        """returns a tuple"""
        return self._config.get('fieldname', 
                                Parent.fieldname
                                )
```

Comment: Have you tried `super(Child, self).fieldname`?

Comment: "I am somehow exposing the property objects, and not calling/executing them." -- what does that mean? How are you calling them in your code now, what is happening, and what should be happening?

Comment: I was calling `Parent.fieldname` which returns a property object (ie `<property object at 0x1007a5788>`).  I meant to call `Parent().fieldname` however using `super()` works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property` objects are [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which means they are automatically bound to an instance when accessed as an attribute (this is also how methods are created).

If you wanted to access a parent `property` object, you could just bind it manually by calling the `descriptor.__get__()` method and passing in `self`:

```
Parent.fieldname.__get__(self))
```

The `property.fget()` method is simply the original, un-decorated function object. You'd call it like any unbound method, you'd pass in `self` manually again:

```
Parent.fieldname.fget(self)
```

or bind it like a method, then call:

```
Parent.fieldname.fget.__get__(self)()
```

Last, but not least, you could use the [`super()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to take care of the binding for you:

```
super(Child, self).fieldname
```

which finds the next object in the MRO (method resolution order) of the class hierarchy that has a `fieldname` attribute and binds it just like the explicit example above.

Personally, I prefer the `super()` option; it best documents that you want to access the original, now overridden property.

Demo:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...     @property
...     def fieldname(self):
...         """returns a tuple"""
...         return (1, 10)
... 
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     @property
...     def fieldname(self):
...         """returns a tuple"""
...         return self._config.get(
...             'fieldname', 
...             super(Child, self).fieldname)
... 
>>> child = Child()
>>> child._config = {}
>>> child.fieldname
(1, 10)
>>> child._config['fieldname'] = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> child.fieldname
('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Thanks. `super(Child, self).fieldname` works.

I also realized what my confusion was -- I was trying to call `Parent.fieldname` as if it were a classmethod... not `Parent().fieldname` -- which does what I wanted.

Comment: That only works because that specific property is not using `self`. You are creating a new instance and accessing the property on that (in the process binding it to that independent new instance).

Comment: Exactly. The parent package opted to not use any class variables and expose everything though class methods via  `@property` decorators.  The instance is irrelevant to these concerns, the class is all that matters.  Still, I used the more-correct `super` method.